# Possible for using a surrogate to buy a .it domain?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

I'm a US citizen interested in buying an Italian TLD (`*.it`). However, those domains can only be registered by EU citizens or residents, or businesses with a registrant who is an Italian citizen and resident.

Are there companies that provide a 'surrogate' like service? They fulfill the requirements for registration but I can administer the domain properties? What are they and what can I expect to pay for the middleman?

Or am I a horrible person for even considering 'circumventing' the intent of the restriction?

Comment: If there is a way to use a surrogate service, it would be pretty risky on your part. According to the Registrar, that 'middleman' owns your domain. Also, you're not a horrible person to attempt to get a domain name that suits your purposes. As time goes on, it becomes harder and harder to find good domain names.

Comment: You're not a horrible person, it's completely legal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GoDaddy

> "You can register .it domain names if your country of origin is Italy,
>   if you are a member of the European Union, or if you use a trustee
>   service (which we provide upon registration)."

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5359/registering-it-domain-names

> "If you do not meet the residency requirements, we automatically charge
>   you a trustee vendor fee of $19.99 per year. The trustee helps you
>   meet the residency requirement and is a third-party vendor. If someone
>   contacts the trustee with an issue regarding your domain name, the
>   trustee contacts us, and then we contact you."

Comment: Well, that was simple. I had been trying to move everything off GoDaddy (cause of their ads, the elephant bit, and just generate eye-bleeding design). But the trustee bit wasn't something that Hover.com, the service I've been moving to, offered. 

"You must use a fee-based trustee service (we will provide) to proceed. This fee is $19.99 per year of domain registration and will automatically be added." <- $19.99 doesn't seem like a bad price for that service.

The domain hasn't appeared immediately in my cart after purchase but figure its just a matter of the Italian reg bit to happen.

Comment: @MatthewReinbold GoDaddy may not be the prettiest registrar but when you call them they answer and are in the US which is nice. The price is pretty good.